# Save and Restore Launchpad Layout?

Tags: launchpad

I've spent a lot of time arranging the apps the way I want them on my Mac and would like for them to stay that way. Is there anyway to save the current layout of Launchpad for a later restore if it gets all mixed up again? I already know about [LaunchpadCleaner 2](http://zoltanb.co.uk/launchpadcleaner/) but would rather not buy an AIR app.

Comment: Not to mention that LaunchpadCleaner is completely useless if you don't buy it...

Answer (score 4):

The database it uses (a simple sql database) is located in ~/Library/Application Support/Dock. That holds all your apps and their placement.

You could back up the file (or simply use TM) so that it can be restored at a later date.

Comment: I tried backing up that file and restoring it. Unfortunately after relaunching the Dock all it did was keep the apps in the pages I set them but not in the order I placed them.